# A or B; A and B

Tags: conjunctions

[i] He doesn’t like A **or** B.
[ii] He doesn’t like A **and** B.

Do both the examples mean the same thing? Or is there any difference?

Comment: I think you will find your answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189916/i-dont-like-potatoes-or-ice-cream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the difference between *and* and *or* is that *and* refers to both, while *or* refers to one or the other but not both. For example:

> He wants to bring Daisy or Joan to the dance.

means he wants to take either Daisy or Joan, but:

> He wants to bring Daisy and Joan to the dance.

means he wants to take both Daisy and Joan.

---

Including the "not", though, complicates the matter somewhat.

> He doesn't like Daisy or Joan.

is usually interpreted as:

> He likes neither Daisy nor Joan.

and so he probably wouldn't want to take either one of them to the dance.

In contrast:

> He doesn't like Daisy and Joan.

could be interpreted as he doesn't like the two of them together. He might like Daisy, and he might like Joan, but perhaps he doesn't like them both together (maybe they quarrel a lot).